# select2 not working with hidden parent div (dynamicaly created select elements)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I'm dynamicaly creating divs with a select2 select element. The problem is, it somehow loosk like it doesn't find the object when initializing the select2.

has anyone run into that problem before?

this is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<button id="addNewDocument" class="col-2 btn btn-primary add-doc-button">Neues Dokument</button>

<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="docDescription" class='col-md-4 form-group documentDescription'>
        <label class='control-label input-label'>Dokumenttyp</label>
        <select class='form-control documentDescriptionSelect required' name='Chose Documenttype'>
            <option value=""></option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.DocumentTypes)
            {
                <option class="row" value='@item.Documentcode'>
                    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Documentcode)</div>
                    <div> - </div>
                    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Documentname)</div>
                </option>
            }
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#addNewDocument").click(function () {
    var uid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + Date.now()
    var selectID = uid + 1;
    var newDocumentBox = $("<li class='row documentContainer justify-content-between' id='" + uid + "'></li>").prependTo("#newDocuments");
    var newDocumentDescription = $("#docDescription").clone(true);
    $("#docDescription").children().eq(1).attr("id", selectID);
    newDocumentDescription.appendTo(newDocumentBox);
    var newDroppableBox = $("<div class='documents col-md-7 droppableBox' ></div>").appendTo(newDocumentBox);
    var newDeleteButton = $("<div class='close-container deleteButton' onclick='deleteDocument(" + uid + ")'><div class='leftright'></div><div class='rightleft'></div></div>").appendTo(newDroppableBox);

    $(selectID).select2({
        placeholder: "Bitte wählen Sie einen Dokumenttyp"

    })
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem, not working when parent is display none.